# How to create a tree representing namespaces from their string representations

Tags: c#, parsing, tree, namespaces, treeview

How can I create a tree-like data structure for the namespaces.

For example, for these namespaces:

```
Enums.NEWENUMS.NEW1
Enums.NEWENUMS.NEW2
Enums.NEWENUMS.NEW3
Enums.OLDENUMS
Enums.TEST.SUB
Enums.TEST.SUB.OK
```

And then load it into a treeview like shown below:

[image]

I tried to split the namespaces, but for the life of me I can't think of a logic to generate it correctly.

Also tried to generate it the way you generate a directory structure, but can't get my head around it since namespaces need splitting.

Comment: `namespace Enums.NEWENUMS`, `namespace Enums.OLDENUMS` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 1. Parsing namespace

Here is the class that represents namespace. It represents namespace as a dictionary of directly nested namespaces. To generate `Namespace`s from strings it provides static methods that use [recursive calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) and [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx):

```
public class Namespace : IDictionary<String, Namespace>
{
    #region Static

    public static IEnumerable<Namespace> FromStrings(IEnumerable<String> namespaceStrings)
    {
        // Split all strings
        var splitSubNamespaces = namespaceStrings
            .Select(fullNamespace =>
                fullNamespace.Split('.'));

        return FromSplitStrings(null, splitSubNamespaces);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Namespace> FromSplitStrings(Namespace root, IEnumerable<IEnumerable<String>> splitSubNamespaces)
    {
        if (splitSubNamespaces == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("splitSubNamespaces");

        return splitSubNamespaces
            // Remove those split sequences that have no elements
            .Where(splitSubNamespace =>
                splitSubNamespace.Any())
            // Group by the outermost namespace
            .GroupBy(splitNamespace =>
                 splitNamespace.First())
            // Create Namespace for each group and prepare sequences that represent nested namespaces
            .Select(group =>
                new
                {
                    Root = new Namespace(group.Key, root),
                    SplitSubnamespaces = group
                        .Select(splitNamespace =>
                            splitNamespace.Skip(1))
                })
            // Select nested namespaces with recursive split call
            .Select(obj =>
                new
                {
                    Root = obj.Root,
                    SubNamespaces = FromSplitStrings(obj.Root, obj.SplitSubnamespaces)
                })
            // Select only uppermost level namespaces to return
            .Select(obj =>
                obj.Root)
            // To avoid deferred execution problems when recursive function may not be able to create nested namespaces
            .ToArray(); 
    }

    #endregion



    #region Fields

    private IDictionary<String, Namespace> subNamespaces;

    #endregion


    #region Constructors

    private Namespace(String nameOnLevel, Namespace parent)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nameOnLevel))
            throw new ArgumentException("nameOfLevel");

        this.Parent = parent;
        this.NameOnLevel = nameOnLevel;
        this.subNamespaces = new Dictionary<String, Namespace>();

        if (this.Parent != null)
        {
            this.Parent.Add(this.NameOnLevel, this);
        }
    }

    private Namespace(String nameOfLevel)
        : this(nameOfLevel, null)
    {

    }

    #endregion


    #region Properties

    public String NameOnLevel
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public String FullName
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.Parent == null)
                return this.NameOnLevel;

            return String.Format("{0}.{1}",
                this.Parent.FullName,
                this.NameOnLevel);
        }
    }

    private Namespace _Parent;

    public Namespace Parent
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Parent;
        }
        private set
        {
            if (this.Parent != null)
                this.Parent.Remove(this.NameOnLevel);

            this._Parent = value;
        }
    }

    #endregion



    #region IDictionary implementation

    public void Add(string key, Namespace value)
    {
        if (this.ContainsKey(key))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Namespace already contains namespace with such name on level");

        this.subNamespaces.Add(key, value);
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(string key)
    {
        return this.subNamespaces.ContainsKey(key);
    }

    public ICollection<string> Keys
    {
        get { return this.subNamespaces.Keys; }
    }

    public bool Remove(string key)
    {
        if (!this.ContainsKey(key))
            throw new KeyNotFoundException();

        this[key]._Parent = null;

        return this.subNamespaces.Remove(key);
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(string key, out Namespace value)
    {
        return this.subNamespaces.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    }

    public ICollection<Namespace> Values
    {
        get { return this.subNamespaces.Values; }
    }

    public ICollection<Namespace> Subnamespaces
    {
        get { return this.subNamespaces.Values; }
    }

    public Namespace this[string nameOnLevel]
    {
        get
        {
            return this.subNamespaces[nameOnLevel];
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("value");

            Namespace toReplace;

            if (this.TryGetValue(nameOnLevel, out toReplace))
            {
                toReplace.Parent = null;
            }

            value.Parent = this;
        }
    }

    public void Add(KeyValuePair<string, Namespace> item)
    {
        this.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        foreach (var subNamespace in this.subNamespaces.Select(kv => kv.Value))
        {
            subNamespace._Parent = null;
        }

        this.subNamespaces.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<string, Namespace> item)
    {
        return this.subNamespaces.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<string, Namespace>[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        this.subNamespaces.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return this.subNamespaces.Count; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<string, Namespace> item)
    {
        return this.subNamespaces.Remove(item);
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, Namespace>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.subNamespaces.GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion



    #region Overrides

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.FullName;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**P.S:** This class may have few incorrectly implemented methods.

**P.S.1:** Parsing methods can be rewritten without LINQ. Actually this LINQ solution is not very idiomatic or a really good example of how and when to use LINQ. But it is short and mostly simple.

## 2. Adding namespaces to the TreeView

You haven't mentioned the UI framework you use, so I have defaulted to Windows Forms. Assuming that you have added TreeView named `treeView_Namespaces` to the form:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var namespaceStrings = new String[]
    {
        "Enums.NEWENUMS.NEW1",
        "Enums.NEWENUMS.NEW2",
        "Enums.NEWENUMS.NEW3",
        "Enums.OLDENUMS",
        "Enums.TEST.SUB",
        "Enums.TEST.SUB.OK"
    };

    var namespaces = Namespace.FromStrings(namespaceStrings);

    AddNamespaces(this.treeView_Namespaces.Nodes, namespaces);
}

void AddNamespaces(TreeNodeCollection nodeCollection, IEnumerable<Namespace> namespaces)
{
    foreach (var aNamespace in namespaces)
    {
        TreeNode node = new TreeNode(aNamespace.NameOnLevel);
        nodeCollection.Add(node);

        AddNamespaces(node.Nodes, aNamespace.Subnamespaces);
        node.Expand();
    }
}
```

## 3. If you need to generate such tree from real namespaces

To do that you will have to walk through types in the [Assembly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173099.aspx) and get all their namespaces:

For example, this code get all types in the currently executing Assembly:

```
var namespaceStrings = Assembly
    .GetExecutingAssembly()
    .GetTypes()
    .Select(type =>
        type.Namespace)
    .Where(@namespace =>
        @namespace != null);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, works like a charm. Quick question though is it possible to add the types in that reside in the namespaces? Can't thank you enough. Thanks again.